# How to optimize MySQL for handling a small database, i.e. < 100mb?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I'm working on designing a base that will probably stay **smaller than 100 MB**, has its own server, and is going to be read and modified through an intranet Java EE web application. I've found a lot of references on optimizing for large bases, and I know that is a much more critical issue, but I've got lots of time, read/insertion speed is a project priority, and I'm pretty sure I can take advantage of such a small total db size, somehow. Unless MySQL is already naturally optimized for that kind of small benchmark, of course.

**It does fit on memory, of course, but I need its data to actually persist, on disk**, or at least be saved to disk before long; I've thought of some crazy-sounding alternatives, like sequentially loading up the whole base into memory at the first time its needed (at user connection time, likely?), in some way, and commiting it later to disk.

But I thought it better to ask it here and see if someone's faced this kind of situation before, and **had a decent idea for profiting from small base size**.

I'm thinking more **in terms of database access and not structure**, though if someone has structure design tips for small bases and believes they make the issue of access optimization completely irrelevant, stating that is probably an appropriate response as well.

Thanks in advance.

*Edit: the app is kinda critical and after I'm done it will be developed by guys who are mostly used to MySQL, so different DBMS aren't much of an option unless they're veeery similar to MySQL.*

Comment: Just make sure mysql's caches are set to be larger than the db's size and it'll naturally cache itself in memory as you work on the table.

Comment: I've thought of that, wasn't confident that it would work that way though. Seems pretty smooth, pretty sure I'm going to just do that then. Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually running into performance problems? It seems like you may be attempting premature optimization. First, implement the application, then benchmark it, and finally optimize it if the benchmark shows serious bottlenecks.

Comment: I wasn't running into performance problems, this was about best practices. I wanted to know if there was a best way of designing small databases, in the sense of taking their size into account; if doing it in such an optimized way didn't incur any additional development time or costs, there'd be no reason to develop the solution in a non-optimized way.

Of course it's unlikely to have made much of a difference in my project, but if this question got a zero-cost solution, and everyone in this site started optimizing their small databases with it, maybe we'd save some processing, globally lol

Answer (score 1):

Databases were made to handle just this kind of thing so most of the infrastructure is there for you.

The onus is just on you to:

- Create appropriate indexes based on the data, the volumn and the dbms.
- Normalize data.
- Apply good validations - not nulls, uniques, etc.
- Use explain plan to see how queries can be speeded up - different for every situation.
- Use caching to improve performance.
- Ensure all table has unique primary keys defined (obvious perhaps, but still required).

Comment: Well, that's all common sense for bases of all sizes, isn't it? Though I guess you might be on to something on customizing indexes specifically for small bases, perhaps by choosing some higher-complexity-class structure that retrieves better in low-order cases... when you say simply "Use caching to improve performance", do you mean caching the whole base or something more intrincate? Thanks!

Comment: I mean set caching on so that repeat of individual queries can run faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at membase - I'm told very good things regarding performance and persistence.  Essentially a memory "database" that gets persisted to disk.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but I've seen some posts from mid-2011 in membase boards and it was clear that it wasn't yet stable enough to be deployed in a production environment, is it that much better now? Also, how similar is it to MySQL? I'm moving away from this country after I'm done with the project, and the guys that are going to maintain it afterwards are really only used to MySQL. Thank you!

Comment: Apparently it's now called Couchbase? : http://www.couchbase.com/membase so it certainly looks like it's progressed from your last view.  As far as compatibility goes, I can't really comment - I've seen membase used in conjunction with mysql in some php projects and always assumed they were closely related - I may have assumed a little more than I should on that.

Comment: Seems interesting, it's based on memcached, which is quite stable already, and key-value storage would definitely suit my needs. Still, like most NoSQL servers, it seems to be made for scaling across distributed clusters and such. Those PHP projects you've seen, were they that big? I'm concerned that this distribution-orientation might make its API a little cumbersome for a smaller project like mine.